# KsqlDB Materialization Exception on the pull query

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've created a pull table from two push tables based on some aggregations. As soon as I try to query the pull table I'm getting Materialization exception.

`TABLE1 - Push table`
`TABLE2 -Push table` 
`TABLE3- Materialized Table formed from TABLE1 & TABLE2`

Code Base:

```
    CompletableFuture<List<Row>> result =
        ksqlClient
            .executeStatement(createTable1Query) // create table1(push table)
            .thenCompose(
                e ->
                    ksqlClient
                        .executeStatement(createTable2Query) // create table2(push table)
                        .thenCompose(
                            c -> ksqlClient.executeStatement(createMaterializedTable)) //create Pull table(Materialized)
                        .thenCompose(x -> ksqlClient.executeQuery("select * from table3;"))); // query the pull table
```

Exception:

````
 {"@type":"generic_error","error_code":50000,"message":"io.confluent.ksql.execution.streams.materialization.MaterializationException: Unable to execute pull query: io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Error executing query locally at node http://U-myname:8088/: Failed to scan materialized table"}
    ```
````